# passing version of a dependency during a release build in maven

Tags: maven

I have a mvn job A which is dependent on mvn job B. The versions of job A and job B are exactly the same. So instead of editing the pom file very time, I do the following in properties section:

```
   <properties>
        <jobBVersion>${project.version}</jobBVersion> 
   </properties>
```

This works for a snapshot build but not for a release build of job A. It fails with the error that snapshot dependencies of job B are still present.
How can I fix this issue so that I need not edit this file even for a release build?

I tried the following(with the above line in general config section still intact) but I still get the same error:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-release-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <jobBversion>${project.version}</jobBversion>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a multi-module Maven project? Are `jobA` and `jobB` two modules of it?

Comment: No. They are independent jobs.. but the version # will remain the same forever...

Comment: What do you mean the version number will remain the same? Releasing should bump the version. And since they are unrelated, Maven can't automatically detect that you want to depend on a release version, if the POM uses a snapshot dependency, so you'll need to manually modify the POM to explictly use the release version.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment. What is meant is the version # of job A and job B will always match. if job B is 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, job A is also  1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. If job B is released as 1.0.0 now I will release job A as 1.0.0 . The versions of these two jobs are always the same. So after releasing job B, i do not want to edit job A's pom file to enter the new version #of job B. I just want to hit perform maven release and it should automatically modify Job A's snapshot version to release version AND also take the version of job A as the release version

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. Perhaps you could use [`versions-maven-plugin:use-releases`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html) mojo to force the use of the release version of `jobB` in the dependencies of `jobA` when performing a release of `jobA`. Like running `mvn versions:use-releases release:prepare release:perform`.

Comment: Ok.. thanks! I will try it